# Unexpected if on line 7?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I been trying to make a chat system but I keep getting errors, this is the last error I have is unexpected if on line 7

line 7:

```
if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['Name']))
```

code

```
<?php
//
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=chat', 'root', '')

//secure the chat

if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['Name']))
{
    $text = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['text']))
    if(!empty($text) && !empty($name))
    {
        $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('', '".$name"', '".$text"')");
        $insert->execute();

        echo "<li class='cm'><b>".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$text."</li>";
    }
}
?>
```

and in case my html form is incorrect

```
<?php

//Get username
$user = $_GET['Name'];
require 'getmessages.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Private system</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javscript/functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="chatContainer">
  <div class="chatHeader">
     <h3>Welcome <?php echo ucwords($user); ?></h3>
   </div>
   <div class="chatMessages"></div>
   <div class="chatBottom"></div>
      <form action="connect.php" id="chatForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="Name" value="<?php echo $user;?>" />
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" placeholder="Type your Message" />
        <input type='submit' name="submit" id="submit" value="Send"/>
      </form>
</div>        
<body>
</html>
```

thanks for anyone who helps :)

Comment: missing semicolon ; on pdo line

Comment: and on strip_tags line 9

Comment: Don't use the code snippets feature if the code is not executable in the browser.

Comment: ... and on the $text = strip_tags line.

Comment: I'd vote to close this as offtopic - typographical error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **semicolon** on following lines:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=chat', 'root', '')
```

**And**

```
$text = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['text']))
```

**Second** issue is that you didn't define the form method `POST` in `<form>`

```
<form action="connect.php" id="chatForm">
```

**This should be:**

```
<form action="connect.php" id="chatForm" method="post">
```

**Third** issue is that you are missing name attribute in name input and try to get `$_POST["name"]` this will return nothing:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Name" value="<?php echo $user;?>" />
```

**This should be:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="Name" value="<?php echo $user;?>" name="Name" />
```

**Side note:**

Don't know about this `$user = $_GET['Name'];` if you are getting it from `URL` than you can use it as:

```
$user = isset($_GET['Name']) ? $_GET['Name'] : "";
```